# Ember serve: every port is in use

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When I specify no port or set the port explicitly, I always see:

```
ember serve --port 4207
Port 4207 is already in use.
```

It doesn't seem to matter which port I pick.

When I start with port 0 (let the cli pick an available port) it starts on on something around 30000~40000.

I am on a Mac. I just upgraded my ember-cli to `3.12.0`

Also: If I start another ember app I have locally, it will run on port 4200. But then I stop it and start the above app and it won't start on that port.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`portfinder`](https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder), which is a subdependency of Ember CLI, released a new version `1.0.22` a few hours ago (August 17, 2019). That one breaks `ember serve`. You will see a port in use error for all ports.

If you are unsure which version of `portfinder` is used in your project, you could run `yarn why portfinder` or `npm list | grep portfinder`.

**Update**: `portfinder@1.0.23` was released today (August, 19 2019). It rolls back to `1.0.21` and therefore fixes the issue. You should upgrade to that new release.

**The following work-a-rounds are outdated by new release of `portfinder`.**

There are two work-a-round known so far:

**1. Downgrading `portfinder` to `1.0.21`.**

You could use [yarn's resolutions feature](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) to do so. Add this to your `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
  "ember-cli/portfinder": "1.0.21"
}
```

Don't forget to run `yarn install` afterwards.

If using npm, you could enforce installing dependencies released before today using the [`--before` option](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#before): `npm install --before 2019-08-16`

**2. Using `ember serve --port 0`**

You could start `ember serve` with `--port 0` argument. In that case portfinder picks up a random port. This seems to work. The port used is reported in terminal, e.g.

> Build successful (1911ms) – Serving on http://localhost:18780/

The bug is reported [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/8794). Hopefully it will be resolved soon.